# Move fancybox 2.0 close button outside of wrapper

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to position the Fancybox 2 close button to the top right corner of the window. Changing the position of .fancybox-close class only moves it inside the fancybox wrapper.

Any idea how to position it outside of the wrapper to the corner of the window and not the corner of the fancybox wrapper? changing the position to *fixed* as mentioned in another question didn't change anything.

```
.fancybox-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px !important;
    right: 15px !important;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 8040;
}
```

Comment: when you say position fixed doesn't change anything, what does it do?  It should work as that's how to position elements relative to your viewport rather than it's parent element

Comment: unfortunately nothing happens. absolute and fixed have the same result. it still aligns to the parent element and not the viewport.

Comment: then you are doing it wrong - http://jsfiddle.net/h2q8v360/ (see the difference between absolute and fixed).  Can you create a snippet that replicates your error

Comment: hmm...yes, i totally get what you're saying and am confused myself. i just tried it out with another project on which i've used fancybox – works there. will see if i can find any differences...

Comment: when you say window, do you mean the browser window or the popup window

Comment: i meant the browser window. i've replaced the script / css with the source file, started from scratch and now it works. sorry for the confusion.